# How to pull resultset of object along group properties using Hibernate Criteria

Tags: hibernate, spring

i am looking for a way to deliver Collection, java.util.map, of objects along their group properites using hibernate criteria in Spring.

**Example Domain**

```
MyDomain {

     private String x;
     private String y; 
     private String pos; 
  //---Getters & Setters ----

 }
```

i like to have collection of

```
  Map<String(X),Map<String(Y),List<MyDoamin>>
```

. For which i am using detached criteria . So far i am able group the properties but i dont know how to add whole object in resultset which i can further transform in Map using result transformer.

> ```
>  DetachedCriteria detachedCriteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(MyDomain.class);
>
>    detachedCriteria
>                 .setProjection(
>                                Projections.projectionList().add(Projections.groupProperty(X))
>                                              .add(Projections.groupProperty(Y))
>                                ).addOrder(Order.asc(X))
>                                 .addOrder(Order.asc(Y))
>
>
>
>  Object o = this.getHibernateTemplate().findByCriteria(detachedCriteria);
> ```

**EDIT**

Currently i am loading whole list of MyDomain in Dao Class und initlizing map in service class which look like.

> ```
>     Map<String, Map<String,List<MyDomain>>> ret =
>                 new HashMap<String, Map<String, List<MyDomain>>>>();
>     try
>     {
>
>         List<MyDomain> myDomains = this.myDomainDao.findAll();
>         Collections.sort(myDomains);
>         for (MyDomain myDomain : myDomains)
>         {
>             String x = myDomain.getX();
>             String y = myDomain.getY();
>
>             if (ret.get(x) == null)
>             {
>
>                 ret.put(x, new HashMap<String,List<MyDomain>>());
>             }
>
>
>
>             if (ret.get(x).get(y) == null)
>             {
>                 ret.get(x).put(y, new ArrayList<MyDomain>());
>
>             }
>
>             ret.get(x).get(y).add(myDomain);
>
>         }
>
>     }
>     catch (Exception e)
>     {
>         this.logger.warn(e);
>         this.logger.debug(e.getMessage());
>     }
>
>
>     return ret;
> ```

My effort is to avoid above written code in service and try to do it in hibernate.

Thanks in advance.
Rehman

Answer (score 0):

The `groupProperty` method doesn't do what you thiks it does. It only makes sense if your query aggregates several rows using an aggregation function (sum, count, etc.), and applies a `group by` clause to the query.

What you need is pure Java code:

```
List<MyDomain> domains = // find the MyDomain entities you want
Map<String, Map<String, List<MyDomain>>> domainsByXThenY = new HashMap<String, Map<String, List<MyDomain>>>();
for (MyDomain d : domains) {
    String x = d.getX();
    Map<String, List<MyDomain>> mapForX = domainsByXThenY.get(x);
    if (mapFoxX == null) {
        mapForX = new HashMap<String, List<MyDomain>>();
        domainsByXThenY.put(x, mapForX);
    }
    String y = d.getY();
    List<MyDomain> listForY = mapForX.get(y);
    if (listForY == null) {
        listForY = new ArrayList<MyDomain>();
        mapForX.put(y, listForY);
    }
    listForY.add(d);
}
```

Comment: yup , you are right. currently i am doing same as you mentioned in your post but i was thinking perhaps such functionality already available in hibernate criteria.